# SQLのSELECT SUM（CASE WHEN ～ ELSE NULL END） でNULLを文字にするやり方について

Tags: sql, postgresql

タイトルの通りなのですが、SUMで集計して結果がNULLの場合に「無」のように文字で結果を表示するようにしたいものの、処理がうまくできません。
今は
 SELECT
   SUM(CASE WHEN A THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
としているため、ヒットしないところはNULLとなり空欄になっています。

↑のNULLのところを文字で置換してみたり、COALESCEやISNULLを使ってもみたのですが、どうにもうまくできませんでした。

どなたかご教授頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 元のSQLを実行できる形で提示されると良いと思います。

Comment: 不慣れなもので申し訳ないのですが、実行できる形というのは、テーブルの内容や実際のSQL文まで載せたほうが良いということでしょうか？

Comment: 実際のSQLがベストですが、名前を伏せるなど必要な編集をして掲載すると、回答が付きやすいです。この質問に関しては格納されているデータは不要と思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！今回は回答を頂いた方の方法で解決できたのですが、次からはうまく伏せてSQLを載せるようにしてみます！

Comment: unaristさん、分かりやすい回答ありがとうございました！
SUMの結果をキャストすることでうまく表示することができました！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bool型の列に対して、trueとなっている行をカウントしたい、という話でしょうか。

SUMの結果をCOALESCEに通せばいいとは思いますが、COALESCEに渡す値の型を揃えないといけません。というか揃えられてしまいます。例えば次のSQLではSUMの結果は int なので、`'無'` も int に変換しようとします…が、できないのでエラーになります。

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A THEN 1 ELSE NULL END), '無')
-- ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "無"
```

ですから、SUMの方を明示的に文字列に変換しなければなりません。SQLで型変換を行う際には `CAST( value AS type )` とします。

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN A THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS text), '無')
```

PostgreSQLの場合、こういう書き方もできます。

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)::text, '無')
```